# This is about the Repository layer when implementing a clean architecture using Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, clean-architecture

This [Repository](https://github.com/Uuttssaavv/flutter-clean-architecture-riverpod/blob/master/lib/features/authentication/domain/repositories/auth_repository.dart#L5)
I'm learning how to develop apps along clean architecture while using Riverpod with Flutter. However, there are implementation methods for which the benefits are unclear.

I can see the advantage of creating an abstract class for the Datasource layer part and directing dependencies to the abstract class rather than the concrete class. (Useful for improving the ease of refactoring when changing the package used or changing the concrete Datasource class for each platform)
However, I don't understand the benefit of dividing the Repository layer class into abstract classes and concrete classes.
I'm using Reiverpod so it shouldn't be for DI purposes.
Also, I don't understand the benefit of creating an abstract class over a concrete class, such as in the Usecase layer.

Why is the Repository class implemented with an abstract class and a concrete class? What are the benefits?

Answer (score 2):

I think the pattern is learned from Java, where "implements" (for mocking during testing) can only be used on abstract classes.

But in Dart, we can use "implements" on a concrete class, so it is now my general pattern to make a concrete class for the repository, and merely "implement" that for my mock repository for testing.  Then, there's only two files to keep in sync, not three.  Simple economy without loss of responsibility.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Just to confirm, does that mean that an abstract class is not necessary for the so-called `Repository` or `Usecase` class?

Comment: My Usecase classes are concrete, inside riverpod providers, which i put into three layers: stateful controllers, stateful services, and stateless repositories.  To swap out a lower layer for testing, I use riverpod's override mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In other words, there is no need for abstract classes in the Usecase layer classes. So, is it okay to say that we don't need an abstract class for the Repository layer class?

Comment: I had a misunderstanding. Does `Usecase` layer (or `Application layer`) mean that we don't create it in the first place?